# How GRPC handle pointer that appear more then once?

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

For example (golang):

```
type {
  Product struct {
    Name string
  }
  Customer struct {
    Name string
    Products []*Product
  }
}
```

Which is the correct behavior:

1. `GRPC` honor the `*Product` pointer and transfer it only once.
2. `GRPC` will transfer the same `*Product` as many times as it associated to different `Customer`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296006/751579) gives two pieces of information: First, that protobuf itself (the underlying serialization method) is a _tree serializer_ - thus it _does not_ handle repeated references to an object by serializing it only once, materializing a graph on the other end.  But, second, that a particular .NET implementation of protobuf provides graph serialization as an option.  Look for it as an option in the golang protobuf or the golang grpc implementation; it may be there.  (Or maybe not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael,
It is not clear on your message, but I am assuming that you will send a `Customer` as part of your request to a gRPC server.

Golang will marshal the struct into `[]byte` (https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Marshal), so the message will not have such thing as a pointer. It will be just an encoded message. (see
https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/wire.go#L22).

gRPC is not a Golang thing, so a pointer on a side (e.g. server) does not mean it must be a point on the other side (e.g. client).

Finally, answering your question, the expected behavior is `2`. **However**, you may take a deeper look into proto buff serialization (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding). I have no idea how it works, but *maybe* the message is compressed, so repeated `[]bytes` maybe be discarded.